# Downloaded Bitmap is null

Tags: android, bitmap, null

I download a png file from link. But sometimes there is no file. And i have null problem.

How can check whether bitmap is downloaded or not.

```
mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(icon_url.openConnection() .getInputStream())
```

Comment: Surround your code with Try/Catch block

Comment: see this example  http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
if(mIcon==null){
// set fallback Image or retry
 }
```